# C# Backround Worker In Different Namespace/Class WPF

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

**EDIT: Solved by adding missing progress changed event handler.**

I'm porting a WPF VB.net application to C# and am having an issue with a background worker that has a DoWork method in a different class.  I have a suspicion that I am not casting the background worker correctly or I may need a handler?

The vb sample code works fine and the progress bar indicates properly, the C# code seems like it fires the  bw.RunWorkerAsync(); method as it reports as IsBusy=True but there is no other response, progress or calls to the external class (as far as I can tell).

This is a WPF application and the issue is regarding a Usercontrol trying to report progress from a public class outside of the control.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

The C# sample code

```
 namespace testApp.Usercontrols
    public partial class ucHome : UserControl
    {
        public Sharing.clsDownloadCollection foo = new Sharing.clsDownloadCollection(); 
         BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();



     public ucHome()         
{       InitializeComponent();
 }

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        pBar.Maximum = 50000;   //progress bar on ucHome
        pBar.Value = 0;

        **// Indicates IsBusy=True when debugging but can't see any further activity
         bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        //**

    }

 public void bw_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
          var foo=new foo();

         // possible problem?
           foo.DoWork((BackgroundWorker)sender);

        }

        public void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

The external class   different project folder/namespace

```
 namespace testApp.Sharing
{
//different namespace /folder than ucHome
 public class foo 

{
public void DoWork(BackgroundWorker bw)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) {
        i += 1;

        bw.ReportProgress(i - 1);
}
}

}
```

The sample VB code that works as expected.

```
    Public Class ucHome 'user control
Public foo As New foo
Friend WithEvents bw As New BackgroundWorker
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True  
        pBar.Maximum = 50000
        pBar.Value = 0
        bw.RunWorkerAsync() 

    End Sub
    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
          'possible my C# is not casting correctly?
        foo.DoWork(DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)) 

    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
       Me.pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

End Class
```

the class foo that user control calls

```
Public Class foo

  Public Sub DoWork(ByVal bw As BackgroundWorker)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 50000
            i += 1
         bw.ReportProgress(i - 1)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: code doesn't compile as provided.  eg where is "myfoo" defined?  have you confused the local "foo" with a "myfoo" field which is causing your problem?  Also, why cast sender twice (and why store it in a variable and never use it.  Try cleaning up the code so others don't have to wade through chaff like that

Comment: Apologize for my typo (myfoo not intended to be in the post). I have solved it, was missing an event handler for progress changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding missing backgrounder ProgressChanged event handler.